# How to search facebook public posts in Graph API 2.5

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With the recent [news](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/facebook-search-public-posts-privacy-how-to-change-settings-a6705591.html) about facebook adding all public posts to be searchable, I was wondering if is was possible to do this using the Graph API.

I am aware that they removed the ablitity to do this when 2.0 was released, but with the recent news I was wondering if they had backtracked on this now, or they have mentioned they are planning to do so in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't concern the Graph API, just the Facebook.com website. There is nothing that I'm aware of that they would revoke the depreciation of the public post search.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog